# Year 1 timestamp in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I downloaded a dataset that has timestamps from year 0 until today. I know that timestamps cannot use year zero, so I am dropping those rows. However, I cannot convert the year 1 timestamp with `pd.to_datetime`

I am calling `to_datetime` on the entire series, but here is one example that fails. Getting this one example to work will get the entire series to work.

```
pd.to_datetime('15-Jan-0001 00:00:00', format='%d-%b-%Y %H:%M:%S')
```

This fails with this error.

> OutOfBoundsDatetime: Out of bounds nanosecond timestamp: 1-01-15 00:00:00

A thing that does work is
`pd.Series(['15-Jan-0001 00:00:00']).apply(lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x, '%d-%b-%Y %H:%M:%S'))` but this leaves the data type as `object` rather than `datetime`. Setting the series created from that as the index leaves me unable to `.loc` anything.

How can I fix this?

Comment: note: pandas (numpy) datetime [Timestamp Limitations](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#timestamp-limitations)